# Removing a set of variable each time

Tags: bash, machine-learning

I have a question please,
In fact I have a text file where the data is stored: in the first line there is a number indicating the number of observations, the second line the number of variables and from the third line, the data matrix starting: each row represents an individual and each column represents a variable.

For example my data base is composed of 3 observations and 4 variables as follow:

```
3
4
8    5   6   4   1
7    6   1   5   2
4    8   2   7   2
```

the last column represents the class of each observation

I look for a program which gives me 3 (number of variables - 1) data bases, the first is composed of the first variable and the class, the second composed of the first two variables and the class and the third is composed of the first three variable and the last column of classes so my new data bases must be a text format a follow (first row : number of observations, and second row : number of variables)
the first text file will be:

```
3
1
8    1
7    2
4    2
```

the second text file will be:

```
3
2
8    5   1
7    6   2
4    8   2
```

the third text file will be:

```
3
3
8    5   6   1
7    6   1   2
4    8   2   2
```

I have a program which remove a variable each time, I want to midify it so that it gives me what explained above

the program is:

```
#!/bin/sh
#script.sh

#initialisation du compteur
i=0
index=0
nb0=0
nbV=0
tab[1]=0
#fichier="test.txt"
fichier=$1

old_IFS=$IFS
#découper les lignes en fonction du formatage du fichier texte
#pour un autre formatage, modifier l'environnement de la commande read
#en adaptant l'IFS(Internal Field Separator)

while IFS='$\n' read -r ligne; do
#traitement des lignes 1 et 2
if [ "$i" -eq 0 ]; then
echo "nbO : $ligne"
nbO=$ligne
elif [ "$i" -eq 1 ]; then
echo "nbV: $ligne"
nbV=$ligne
while [ "$index" -lt "$nbV" ]
do
echo $nbO >> Output_$(($index+1)).txt
index=$(($index+1))
done
index=0
while [ "$index" -lt "$nbV" ]
do
echo $(($nbV-1)) >> Output_$(($index+1)).txt
index=$(($index+1))
done

else
index=0
IFS=' '
read -a array <<<"$ligne"
#récuperer le nombre de variables à partir 
#de la taille du tableau contenant les variables
nbV=${#array[*]}


while [ "$index" -lt "$nbV" ]
do 

#supprimer l'élement de l'indice index
temp=("${array[@]}")
unset temp[$index]

#echo ${temp[@]} 
#echo ${array[$index]} >> Output_$(($index+1)).txt

echo ${temp[@]} >> Output_$(($index+1)).txt
index=$(($index+1))
done
fi
#incrementation du compteur
i=$(($i+1))
#index=0

done < "$fichier"

IFS=$old_IFS

exit 0

#passer en mode root
#tapez dans la console shell la commande sudo su
#puis entrez votre mot de passe 

#pour créer un script 
#gedit nom_script.sh 

#pour exécuter un script
#donnez les droits d'execution à votre script
#en tapant la commande chmod +x script.sh
#pour executer le script tapez bash script.sh chemin_database
```

I hope I could explain what I want to do and I would be very grateful to anyone who can help me

thank you

a last question please, if i have a matrix

```
8    5   6   4   1
7    8   2   7   2
4    3   2   5   2
```

how can i have the sum of maximums, it means sum of maximums of each row , which is for the example above max first line 8, max second line 8, and max last line 5, i want to have as result 21 which is (8+8+5), thank you very much

Comment: Seems like a plain bash programming question; migrating to SO.

Comment: It seems we are supposed to solve a puzzle

Comment: @fatima If you could use those commands let me know please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk

```
awk 'NR==1{l=$1}
NR==2{t=$1;for (i=1;i<=t;i++) print l RS i> i ".txt"}
NR>2{ for (i=1;i<=t;i++)
         { for (j=1;j<=i;j++0)
              printf $j FS > i ".txt"
           printf $NF RS > i ".txt"
         }
     }' file
```

#### explanation

- `NR==1{l=$1}` get the line 1 and save to var l
- `NR==2{t=$1;for (i=1;i<=t;i++) print l RS i> i ".txt"}` get line 2, and print the title to each file 1.txt, 2.txt, etc
- `NR>2` part, print the result to each file according your request.

if you need run in script, for example, accept the file name as option.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

    awk 'NR==1{l=$1}
    NR==2{t=$1;for (i=1;i<=t;i++) print l RS i> i ".txt"}
    NR>2{ for (i=1;i<=t;i++)
             { for (j=1;j<=i;j++0)
                  printf $j FS > i ".txt"
               printf $NF RS > i ".txt"
             }
         }' $1

# Put your rest script here.
```

after you run the script:  `script.sh text.txt`, you will get below files directly

#### result

```
$ cat 1.txt
3
1
8 1
7 2
4 2

$ cat 2.txt
3
2
8 5 1
7 6 2
4 8 2

$ cat 3.txt
3
3
8 5 6 1
7 6 1 2
4 8 2 2

$ cat 4.txt
3
4
8 5 6 4 1
7 6 1 5 2
4 8 2 7 2
```

#### edit: For the second request to get max and sum, here is the code:

Source file:

```
$ cat file
8    5   6   4   1
7    8   2   7   2
4    3   2   5   2
```

awk command:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) max[NR]=max[NR]>$i?max[NR]:$i}END{for (i in max) sum+=max[i];print sum}' file

21
```

Comment: Dear sir,thank you so much for your response, can you explain me more please, what you have written, i must write it in a .sh script or directly in terminal, and also i want that it gives me results in text files not in terminal because i work with thousands of variables

Comment: a last question please, if i have a matrix 
8    5   6   4   1
7    8   2   7   2
4    3   2   5   2
how can i have the sum of maximums, it means sum of maximums of each row , which is for the example above max first line 8, max second line 8, and max last line 5, i want to have as result 21 which is (8+8+5), thank you very much

Comment: Could you please update these requests in your original question with code format? it will be easy for us to understand.

Comment: See your update, and I edited it with format. Seems this new request has no relationship with your original request. My recommend is, vote up and accept mine, if it already fixed your first problem. Then start a new question with the max+sum one.

Comment: Thanks to let me know, if the answer fixed your problem, you need vote it up, or accept it.

Comment: the second code for summax doesnt work, how can i vote up or accept an answer? thank you

Comment: I have tested the second awk, works find for me. If you need vote up or accept, you should see the arrow and hook on top left on my answer. Click it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok there is just a recommendation:
shouldn't be such difficult...read man page of `join` command
also read man page of `paste` and `cut`...
google `awk` and `sed` command as well